# divides each element of the matrix by 2 if the element is an even number

Tags: list-comprehension, nested-lists

i need to write a function in python that takes a matrix as an argument and divides each element of the matrix by 2 if the element is an even number (otherwise, does nothing).

i also need to use list comprehension for this.

as an example, if i have a matrix like m = [[5, 4], [2, 3], [6, 7]] output: [[5, 2], [1, 3], [3, 7]]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide, what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def f(matrix):
    return [ [x//2 if x%2==0 else x for x in m ] for m in matrix]
print(f([[5, 4], [2, 3], [6, 7]]))
```